# Oracle: Can I select from a list of values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I know it is possible to filter a query from a list as in `Select * from table where ID in (1,2,3,4)`, but is it possible to select from a list?

For example, I'd like to select date and offset date from a list of offset hours:

```
select sysdate, sysdate - offset / 24 as offsetSysdate
from dual, (1,2,3,4) as offset
```

I know I can create a table and populate it with values to do this, but I was looking for a way to do it on the fly directly in the query.

Comment: 1,2,3,4 is just an example, numbers aren't necessarily contiguous or all integers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a database "table of number" type - either create one or use one that handily exists like SYS.KU$_OBJNUMSET:

```
select sysdate, sysdate - offset.column_value / 24 as offsetSysdate
from TABLE (KU$_OBJNUMSET(1,2,3,4)) offset
```

Note that above `offset` is now an alias for the TABLE, and there is a pseudo-column called `column_value` for table types like this.  Also no need for DUAL table.

If you prefer to create your own type:

```
create type num_tab as table of number;
/

select sysdate, sysdate - offset.column_value / 24 as offsetSysdate
from TABLE(num_tab(1,2,3,4)) offset;
```

Comment: thanks, this solution is the simplest and doesnt require selecting from a predefined set or using unions.

Comment: This solution is the most flexible because it also allows for non-contiguous numbers and non-integer numbers.

Comment: @Tony Andrews: Is there an equivalent of KU$_OBJNUMSET in oracle for other types (e.g. strings or datetimes)? Or would you simply use your 2nd example and make it of the desired type?

Comment: There is `SYS.KU$_VCNT` (TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000)) for strings.  I don't know of one for dates.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use a subselect for that

```
select sysdate, sysdate - offset / 24 as offsetSysdate
from
(
    select 1 as offset from dual
    union
    select 2 from dual
    union
    select 3 from dual
    union
    select 4 from dual
)
```

For a more sophisticated way to generate the number sequence, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847226/sql-to-generate-a-list-of-numbers-from-1-to-100).

---

**EDIT:** Brino figured out the suggested code improvement, here it is in readable format and slightly improved:

```
select sysdate, sysdate - offset.value / 24, offset.value as offsetSysdate
from (select r as value
      from (select level r from dual connect by level <= 4)
     ) offset;
```

Comment: thanks, using your link i was able to create a simpler query: `select sysdate, sysdate - offset.value / 24, offset.value as offsetSysdate
from (select r as value from (select level r from dual connect by level <= 100) where r in (1,3,4,5)) offset;`

Comment: @Brino: Good, I'll copy that into my answer.

Comment: @Brino: ... and made some slight improvement

Answer (score 1):

Use the with clause to create a table of offsets:

```
with offset_table(offset) as
( select level lvl
  from dual
  connect by level <= 4
)
select sysdate, sysdate - offset / 24 as offsetSysdate
from offset_table;
```