# How to select a list but return rows from an Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

In Oracle 12c there was a handy way to get result rows by selecting a list:

```
select column_value from TABLE (KU$_OBJNUMSET(2,3,4,7,8));
```

See this SO-answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30173592/669023.

This does not seem to work in 19c anymore, I get:
ORA-00932: Inconsistente datatyps: expected UDT got NUMBER.

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird, but the type name don't suggest it's public API anyway :)

You can always roll your own:

```
create type num_t as table of number;

select column_value from num_t(1,3,5,9);
```