# sql placeholder rows

Tags: oracle, join, oracle-apex, placeholder

I have an apex item `P_USERS` which can have a value higher than the amount of rows returning from the query below.

I have a classic report which has the following query:

```
  select 
       first_name,
       last_name
  from  accounts
  where account_role = 'Author'
  order by account_nr;
```

I want placeholder rows  to be added to the query (`first_name = null`, `last_name = null` etc.), if the total rows from the query is lesser than the value in the `apex_item` `P_USERS`.

Any tips on how to achieve this? Maybe with a `LEFT join`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more result than the minima you defined, you must add the rest with union.

Here is what you could try to adapt to your case:

```
  SELECT i,c FROM  (
select rownum i, c from (
select  'a' c from dual union all select 'b' from dual union all select 'd' from dual union all select 'be' from dual
)), (Select Rownum r From dual Connect By Rownum <= 3)
where (i(+)= r)
union select i,c from (select rownum i, c from (
select  'a' c from dual union all select 'b' from dual union all select 'd' from dual union all select 'be' from dual
)) where i>3
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use a `LEFT JOIN`.

First, create a list of number until the limit you want like [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847226/sql-to-generate-a-list-of-numbers-from-1-to-100):

```
-- let's say you want 300 records
Select Rownum r From dual Connect By Rownum <= 300
```

Then you can use this to left join and have empty records:

```
SELECT C, R FROM  
  ( select rownum i, c from (select  'a' c from dual union all select 'b' from dual) )
, ( Select Rownum r From dual Connect By Rownum <= 300)
where i(+)= r order by r
```

The above gives you an ordered list starting with 'a', 'b', then null until the end.

So you could adapt it to your case so:

```
SELECT F,L FROM  
  ( select rownum i, f, l from (
             select first_name f, last_name l 
               from  accounts where account_role = 'Author'
            order by account_nr) )
, ( Select Rownum r From dual Connect By Rownum <= 300)
where i(+)= r
```

Comment: Thanks you're a lifesaver ;)

Comment: Somehow it doesn't show all records from account, if there are more accounts then rownums defined in the second select statement.

Comment: Sorry, no time to help you right now... maybe a new question could help. Ask wisely.