# Dynamic Generate rows without using loops

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to dynamic generate row from max value
for example if i am passing max value 7 Store procedure should return value
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

without using loops

Comment: Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51320368/8298316)

Comment: In case you are unaware, stored procedures are not standard SQL. Each DBMS has its own, proprietary language for stored procedures. For example, Oracle has PL/SQL and SQL Server has T-SQL. So if you want a relevant answer, I think that you should [edit] your question and write which DBMS you are using. Is it MySQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database youa re using.

Comment: Thank you for suggetions will definately improve my question that gives clear understand of what i am trying to ask.

Comment: I added the `sql-server` tag based on the syntax in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].GenerateSequence 
    @MaxLimit int
    
AS
BEGIN

;with numcte
AS  
(  
  SELECT 1  [Sequence] 
  UNION all  
  SELECT  [Sequence] + 1 FROM numcte WHERE [Sequence] < @MaxLimit
)
select * from numcte

END
```

Comment: USing this you can generate numeric sequence without using loop.just pass max value in Paramter

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server below query will serve you purpose:

```
create procedure generate_list 
@maxLimit int 
as
begin
SELECT DISTINCT n = number 
FROM master..[spt_values] 
WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND @maxlimit
end
```

Then call the store procedure with :

```
exec generate_list 7
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Please, [do not post images of code or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557).

Comment: I have provided code in code section. The image is to share the output of that code. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: You can use [ASCII table generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to show the output. Or just format 7 rows with 1 column manually by putting pipes (`|`) around the header and values and `|-|` after the header to create tabular output. Or create [a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l).