# How to cross join with out using a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, cross-join

Recently, I am trying to create a table. I have a column that contains 'a', 'b', 'c' and would like to cross join it with 1,2,3 in to the table below.

However, I don't have a table that contains values 1,2,3 and need to do it without creating a table.

Can I achieve this without creating any table? Thanks a lot!

```
Col1
a
b
c

Col1 Col2
a   1
b   1
c   1
a   2
b   2
c   2
a   3
b   3
c   3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL to generate a list of numbers from 1 to 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847226/sql-to-generate-a-list-of-numbers-from-1-to-100)

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTE instead:

```
SQL> with
  2  a (col) as
  3    (select 'a' from dual union all
  4     select 'b' from dual union all
  5     select 'c' from dual
  6    ),
  7  b (col) as
  8    (select 1 from dual union all
  9     select 2 from dual union all
 10     select 3 from dual
 11    )
 12  select a.col, b.col
 13  from a cross join b;

C        COL
- ----------
a          1
a          2
a          3
b          1
b          2
b          3
c          1
c          2
c          3

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: sorry may I know is the table dual should exist on by server? because on my server, I dont have a table that contains 1,2,3. Thanks!

Comment: DUAL exists on any Oracle database. It is owned by SYS, but anyone can use it via public synonym.

Comment: In some other RDBMS you can select without specifying a table. In Oracle this is not possible, hence the existence of DUAL which contains a single column "DUMMY" and populated with a single row valued 'X' when the database is installed.

Comment: Yes, thanks I really help. Sorry for asking one more question. If I want to update this result, how can I achieve it? Many thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. How would you want to "update" this result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT LEVEL AS col2 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3);
```

or

```sql
WITH data (col1, col2) AS (
  SELECT col1, 1 FROM table1
UNION ALL
  SELECT col1, col2 + 1 FROM data WHERE col2 < 3
)
SELECT * FROM data;
```

Which, given your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (col1) AS
SELECT 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | COL1 | COL2 |
> | --- | --- |
> | a | 1 |
> | b | 1 |
> | c | 1 |
> | a | 2 |
> | b | 2 |
> | c | 2 |
> | a | 3 |
> | b | 3 |
> | c | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=32e61e90358c856165ed0faa21ed572b)*

Answer (score 1):

You can create "tables" within your query in many different ways, several of which have been illustrated in other answers already.

For your request I like an XML solution as shown below:

```
create table table1 (col1 varchar2(1));
insert into table1(col1) values('a');
insert into table1(col1) values('b');
insert into table1(col1) values('c');
commit;

select t1.col1, xmlcast(column_value as number) as col2
from   table1 t1 cross join xmltable('1 to 3')
;

COL1 COL2
---- ----
a       1
a       2
a       3
b       1
b       2
b       3
c       1
c       2
c       3
```